# how to change the focusedBorder color in custom Reusable Text Field component flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, flutter-textinputfield

I am new to Flutter development. I created a custom Text field component which I am going to use in my application. I am sharing code and can any one help me how to change the text field border line color based on text field  validation. I will reuse this text field for email, password, amount....etc

code:

```
class MyInputWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final FocusNode focusNode;
  final String hint;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final VoidCallback onEditCompleted;
  final show;

  const MyInputWidget(
      {@required this.focusNode,
      @required this.hint,
      @required this.controller,
      @required this.show,
      this.onEditCompleted})
      : assert(focusNode != null),
        assert(hint != null),
        assert(controller != null),
        assert(show != null);

  @override
  _MyInputWidgetState createState() => _MyInputWidgetState();
}

class _MyInputWidgetState extends State<MyInputWidget> {
  TextEditingController _controller;
  FocusNode _focusNode;
  Color focusBorderColor;

  _MyInputWidgetState();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusBorderColor = Colors.blue;
    if (widget.controller != null)
      _controller = widget.controller;
    else
      _controller = TextEditingController();
    if (widget.focusNode != null)
      _focusNode = widget.focusNode;
    else
      _focusNode = FocusNode();

    _focusNode.addListener(() {});
  }

  void listener() {
    if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
      print("focus");
    } else {
      print("nofocus");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(
              width: 1.0,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                  alignment: const Alignment(1.0, 1.0),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    textField(),
                    if (widget.controller.text.isNotEmpty)
                      IconButton(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 3),
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              widget.controller.clear();
                            });
                          })
                    else
                      Container(
                        height: 0.0,
                      )
                  ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller?.dispose();
    _focusNode?.dispose();
  }

  Widget textField() {
    return TextField(
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      controller: _controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: widget.hint,
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: focusBorderColor, width: 3),
        ),
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: focusBorderColor, width: 3),
        ),
      ),
      onSubmitted: (item) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
      },
      onEditingComplete: () {
        //print(widget.show);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FocusNode emailFocusNode = FocusNode();
  bool show = false;
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    emailNotifier();
  }

  emailNotifier() {
    emailFocusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!emailFocusNode.hasFocus) {
        if (emailController.text.isNotEmpty) {
          ValidationHelper().validateEmail(emailController.text).then((result) {
            if (!result) {
              show = true;
              //print("Notifier false");
            } else {
              show = false;
              // print("Notifier true");
            }
            setState(() {});
          });
        }
      } else {
        //print("Test field is empty");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 35),
              child: MyInputWidget(
                focusNode: emailFocusNode,
                hint: "Enter Email",
                controller: emailController,
                show: show,
                onEditCompleted: () {
                 
                },
                
              ),
            ),
            Visibility(child: AlertWidget(), visible: show)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AlertWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AlertWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("Alert"),
      color: Colors.redAccent,
    );
  }
}
```

if the validation failed means I have to change the text field border line color to red otherwise the line color will be blue. I tried to send the Boolean status but I am unable do that.

Comment: You want to change the focus border-color right?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede yes based email validation

Comment: You mean to say that if your email is right then show normal color else show red color?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede yes based on the boolean show value. I am doing visible and invisible operation on AlertWidget() widget which is same class. Here i have to send the status to MyInputWidget  for changing the focus border color

Comment: Maybe you need to use `TextFormField` because it has inbuild `validator function` from you can change the border color

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede I have to validate the text field when there was no focus and i have to write the validation at out side because the main purpose is to reuse this text field component.

Comment: I also created a reusable text field using `TextFormField` in that I also show error and all

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede then can you explain how you share status to text field widget